# How do I use my Airport express to connect an AV receiver that requires ethernet?

Tags: airport

I set up the airport express(AX) in airport utility and I have it extending my network from my airport extreme. Shows connected and everything but when I plug in my AV receiver it does not get the signal. Furthermore when I connect my macbook to the AX via ethernet cable and assign the network to ethernet it does not connect to the internet? My question is how to I configure the AX so that I can receive the wireless signal from my airport extreme and convert it to ethernet connectivity?  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

From the Apple Support [Airport Express FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1515):

> **Question**: Since AirPort Express only has one Ethernet port, does it act as a LAN port, WAN port, or both?
>
> **Answer**: Depending on how you have it set up, the Ethernet port can function as a LAN port (defined as either simple bridging or sharing
>   your Internet connection via network address translation) or a WAN
>   port (connecting to your broadband Internet service provider or
>   upstream router). **However, it never acts as both simultaneously**.
>   By default the AirPort Express Ethernet port acts as a WAN port.
>   **When it is set up as a secondary extended Wi-Fi base station, it can act as a LAN port**. Assuming that your Internet service provider only
>   gives you one IP address (the most common scenario for homes), this
>   means that AirPort Express can only accommodate wired clients when
>   acting as an extender or bridge. Therefore, **if you need to support
>   wired clients and only want to get one base station** (or router, as
>   it's the routing capacity of AirPort Express that is relevant here),
>   **you should get the AirPort Extreme Base Station or Time Capsule instead**.

According to an answer to a question on an [Apple Store page](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MB321LL/A?pqid=QAAFADX9F9KPPDD2P72DKPXF4CAUA9D4J):

> Yes, certainly. Connect Ethernet cable from the Express to your
>   non-wireless computer which meets the above listed "System
>   Requirements" and **use AirPort Utility to direct the Express to "join"
>   your wireless network** from the list which will show on the popup
>   presented to you. **The Express will then function as a wireless adapter**
>   (receiving signals) for your computer, but in that configuration it
>   will not extend the wireless network to other devices.

You can accomplish this task via the Airport Utility. In one Apple discussion forum discussion, a user (Bob Timmons) notes that:

> new AirPort Express 802.11n can be configured to "extend a wireless
>   network". That is a much simpler setup with much higher performance
>   than WDS can offer.

You'll need to use Apple's Airport Utility to set up your Airport Express. Two approaches that you can take are WDS or Extended wireless network, as noted in [this Apple Support KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4145).